# Discord.js fetch user's custom status and issue role

Tags: discord.js

How can I issue a role to a guild member based on their custom status? For instance, if a member has the word "rainbow" within their status, then they are given the role 'Rainbow'?

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. - Some research could/would answer your question. It takes me 2 minutes to answer it, try it yourself! :)

Answer (score 2):

A user's custom status is stored under a [Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities).

You can access a status under `member.presence.activities`, you can listen to the event [`presenceUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) for when a user changes their custom status which is emitted whenever a guild member's presence (e.g. status, activity) is changed.

With this, you can pick up on whatever text set in their status and based on specific words, in your instance if the word "rainbow" is within their status, then give then a role with [GuildMemberRoleManager#add](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add).